# Change class of element on mouseenter/mouseleave event within v-for loop in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to change the class of a single element within v-for loop on a mouseenter/mouseleave event but I'm confused on how to make it so that only the class on the element that is being hovered changes.

I've tried binding the class to a variable but that obviously causes all the elements in the list to change.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-for="item in items" @mouseenter="showInfoBar()" @mouseleave="hideInfoBar()">
        <span class="infobar" :class="{ show : infoBar }"> </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ItemsList',
  props: ['items'],
  data()  {
    return {
      infoBar: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showInfoBar() {
      this.infoBar = true
    },
    hideInfoBar() {
      this.infoBar = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this instead

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" @mouseenter="infoBar = index" @mouseleave="infoBar = null">
        <span class="infobar" :class="{ show : infoBar == index }"> </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Then for your data property,

```js
data()  {
    return {
      infoBar: null
    }
},
```

Comment: since it defaults to null, seems like using just this will work:
` @mouseover="infoBar = index"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `infoBar` representing the state of all the info bars, when they should be controlled independently.

Turning `infoBar` into an array, with each element representing the state of the info bar at that respective index should solve your problem.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-for="(item, index) in items" @mouseenter="showInfoBar(index)" @mouseleave="hideInfoBar(index)">
        <span class="infobar" :class="{ show : infoBar[index] }"> </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ItemsList',
  props: ['items'],
  data()  {
    return {
      infoBar: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.infoBar.push(false);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showInfoBar(index) {
      this.infoBar[index] = true;
    },
    hideInfoBar(index) {
      this.infoBar[index] = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of handling this as an array, the better approach should be handling it as separated components, I mean, is better practice to leave the state of each component to each component instead of handling the state of a collection of "components" in an array, I'm basing on React to this idea, you can declare `ItemsList` and `Item` as different components, and then for each Item, a separate state, please, tell me if you understand this approach, good luck.

## Edition after reading the code

I think also, once you refactor your code, instead of handling the state changing in two different methods, just declare a `toggleMethod()` and make a logical denial to the current value of the state you are looking at the moment.

This is better:

```
function toggleState() {
    this.someState = !this.someState;
}
```

Than this

```
function showState() {
    this.someState = true;
}
function hideState() {
    this.someState = false;
}
```

Good luck mate.

Comment: Ya, it seems that these answers are the only two options and certainly an additional component is much more declarative and elegant.

Comment: Not only that, but also you can handle the state of each item in a given collection separately, which is better than handling it in an array.